# I have mac m1 pro chipset. project is building but not able to run test with robolectric

Tags: android, android-studio

i have enablejetifier = true

Failed to transform '/Users/name/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 59

Comment: I tried enablejetifier = false ,  but then I m getting not able to merge Android manifest file. exact error--     Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.5.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:72:5-552:19 to override

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.